# Does the time that the Avenger spends traveling affect any countdowns?

Tags: xcom-2

I've been unable to tell whether time spent flying from location to location counts towards any of your own timers (research, construction, healing, etc.). That is, I've never had a project finish in midair or upon landing, even though some trips seem to take upwards of half a day. Does it affect any countdowns? It seems like it might still move time forward on alien actions, but I haven't noticed one way or the other.

(note that it at the very least affects achievements, assuming the "Exquisite Timing" achievement for beating it by July 1st works as described)

Comment: I too would like to see a source on that.  I'm pretty sure I've seen wounded soldiers recover during travel, but then travel time accounts for maybe 3% of them passed in the game so it's pretty unlikely to have anything happen.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that it does count, I've had dark events start in the middle of travel several times...  But I think the travel time is relatively quick as far as in-game time (hours vs. days) that I don't think it has much effect unless you're *really* close to an event popping

Comment: I don't entirely understand what happened, but earlier today finished a scan before moving to take care of a resistance mission. After I reached the mission site, I decided to back out of the staging screen to do a couple things in the base to get ready. When I backed out to the geoscape, I suddenly failed the mission for taking too long. Not sure whether that's a yes or a no, but it seems related.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**It appears that the internal timers are identical to the date/time representation shown on the geoscape**: if time's passing on that, the timers are progressing.

However, not all timers are actively checked if the Avenger is airborne: **project-completion and site-expiry events seem to only *trigger* while the game is on the Geoscape screen with the Avenger landed**. Even if the timer for a project or mission site hits zero while the Avenger is in flight to a new location, nothing actually happens until after it has landed at the destination. Since landing at a mission site jumps you straight to the start-mission screen, this means that once you give the 'fly here' order for one things that would normally trigger in-flight are queued up until the next Geoscape visit after the mission ends (or until the player returns to the geoscape using a 'cancel deployment' option, which means such options should be used with care when dealing with time-sensitive missions).

Comment: +1, that would explain the scenario I mentioned in my comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'll need to research your assertion that it doesn't affect your internal progress timers for research/construction/building items.

However, time definitely passes when a UFO is searching for the Avenger.  Time also passes for the countdown you get if the Avatar Project timeline is filled up.  MiloPrice in a comment below also mentions soldier healing progressing while the Avenger is flying.

Comment: I've edited my question to better show (what may be wrong) assumptions on my part. I've only had one UFO search for me so far, but it did move at the same time I was moving, so that's definitely one thing that keeps going.

Comment: I just had a soldier heal while traveling, so at the very least, it advances your soldier injury timer.

Comment: @MiloPrice You sure about that?  I flew for 2 days, and got weird results when I tracked the soldier healing times.  One soldier's # of days ticked down by one, the rest stayed the same.

Comment: I'm pretty sure--in mid-flight, the "Cpl. So-and-So has recovered" toast text popped up at the left side, even though the timers at the right didn't appear, as usual. If I can get it to happen again, I'll try and get a screenshot.